# Convert Hashmap to xml without Hashmap tags using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, hashmap

I need to convert my hashmap to XML without hashmap tags and special characters.

Below is my code to convert hashmap to XML using Jackson library.

```
Map<String, String> messageMap = this.processMessage(message, dd, rawMessage, getYamlConfiguratios(fileName));

Map Contract_Master_Full = new HashMap();
Contract_Master_Full.put("Contract-Master-Full", messageMap);

Map CREATECONTRACT = new HashMap<>();
CREATECONTRACT.put("FCUBS_HEADER",xmlMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(headers).replace("&amp;lt;", "<"));
CREATECONTRACT.put("FCUBS_BODY", xmlMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(Contract_Master_Full).replace("&lt;", "<"));

Map BODY = new HashMap<>();
BODY.put("BODY", xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(CREATECONTRACT).replace("&lt;", "<"));

XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
mapper.writeValue(new File(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH), BODY);
```

Here is my output

```
<HashMap><BODY>&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>&lt;HashMap>&lt;FCUBS_BODY>&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>&amp;#xd;
&lt;HashMap>&amp;#xd;
  &lt;Contract-Master-Full>&amp;#xd;
    &lt;TR_UDF_Name>&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>&amp;amp;#xd;
&lt;HashMap>&amp;amp;#xd;
  &lt;info1>User Info #1&lt;/info1>&amp;amp;#xd;
  &lt;info2>User Info #2&lt;/info2>&amp;amp;#xd;
&lt;/HashMap>&amp;amp;#xd;
&lt;/TR_UDF_Name>&amp;#xd;
    &lt;SecurityType>FOR&lt;/SecurityType>&amp;#xd;
-
-
-
-
```

My expected output should not include ,  and special characters like < & 3xd
Also some xml characters like < is converted to some special characters.

Comment: Do not serialise every map item separately. Just create a map with all items and serialise it at the end. For example, instead of `CREATECONTRACT.put("FCUBS_HEADER",xmlMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(headers).replace("&amp;lt;", "<"));` use `CREATECONTRACT.put("FCUBS_HEADER", headers);`

Comment: Yup, that works